# How do I make two JLabels on opposite sides of the screen?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I'm trying to make something that looks like this:
[image]

As you can see, I want the labels on opposite sides of each other on the same line in the same parent container.

I tried using the `GridBagLayout`, and here is my code:

```java
JPanel cont = new JPanel();

JLabel left = new JLabel("left");
JLabel right = new JLabel("right");

GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
cont.add(left, gbc);

gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
cont.add(right, gbc);
```

Comment: Put a "filler" component between them with a `weighty` of `1`

Comment: Thank you so much!! This worked for me. Do you want to make this an answer so I can mark as accepted?

Comment: No, you can self answer 

Comment: I would use a BorderLayout. Add one component to the BorderLayout.LINE_START and one to the BorderLayout.LINE_END.

Comment: @camickr that's a good solution too, I'm not sure which one I like better

Answer (score -2):

You can use GridBagLayout, but I find using the constraints painful and sometimes unpredictable. This is easier with GridLayout and specifying the justification of the JLabel.

Here's an example that puts two JLabels in a row as in your drawing:

```
JPanel labelrow = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2));
JLabel left = new JLabel("left side", JLabel.LEFT);
JLabel right = new JLabel("right side", JLabel.RIGHT);
```

You can do the same with other controls, like buttons, if you put them inside JPanels with FlowLayouts that are left and right-justified.

Here's an example showing it with buttons off to each side:

```
JPanel buttons = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2));
JPanel left = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
JPanel right = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
left.add(new JButton("Left"));
right.add(new JButton("Right"));
buttons.add(left);
buttons.add(right);
```

Comment: (1-) A GridLayout does not leave space between components. The above code sort of works because of how the text is painted in a JLabel. However it would not work for a JButton which paints a border around the component so you will so there is no space between components.

Comment: It works with buttons if you put them first into JPanels with FlowLayout, then add them to the GridLayout. I do it all the time.